# access udeploy logs from a java web application

Tags: java, web-services

I would like to fetch the console logs of *udeploy* ([IBM urban code deploy](https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/products/urbancode-deploy/)) from a Java web application. Are there any existing plugins or other options for that? (googling already failed)

Comment: could you please explain in detail?